# how to convert a react polygon element to a google.maps.Polygon element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I use the `@react-google-maps/api` library. I want to distinguish if a click on the map will be inside the polygon or not.
My Map [component](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-elbakyan-ixtix?file=/src/Map.js) looks like this:

```
const libraries = ["geometry"];

const Map = ({ onClick, paths }) => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    const { PolyGeometry } = window;
    const { latLng } = event;
    console.log(PolyGeometry.containsLocation(p, latLng));
  };

  const p = (
    <Polygon
      paths={paths}
      strokeColor={"#FF0000"}
      strokeOpacity={0.8}
      strokeWeight={2}
      fillColor={"#FF0000"}
      fillOpacity={0.35}
      draggable={true}
    />
  );
  return (
    <LoadScript
      id="script-loader"
      googleMapsApiKey="MY_API_KEY"
      language="en"
      region="us"
      libraries={libraries}
    >
      <GoogleMap
        mapContainerClassName="App-map"
        center={{ lat: 52.52047739093263, lng: 13.36653284549709 }}
        zoom={12}
        version="weekly"
        on
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        {p}
      </GoogleMap>
    </LoadScript>
  );
};

export default Map;
```

When I click on the map I get this error:

> a.lng is not a function

When I use it in vanilla JS, everything works fine, [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqupyw9g/22/). Since the error message changes depending on which argument I pass in first (if I did `containsLocation(latLng, p)` the error message would be "b.lang ...". So there is something wrong with my `p`.

How do I convert the React Polygon (`p`) element to a  `google.maps.Polygon` element so that I can use it in the `containsLocation(a,b)` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not too familiar with React JS so the below might not be best practice but I spotted a few issues with the code you provided.

First, to get your event "coordinates" you should use:

```
const { latLng } = event.latLng;
```

I suppose you can create a google maps Polygon by doing this:

```
const polygon = new window.google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: paths
});
```

Then check your coords this way:

```
window.google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latLng, polygon)
```

This should work without issues. There probably is a way to access the Google Maps Polygon without "creating" it like I did here by using props.

Comment: woahhhhhm, thanks again, could have figured this out myself, thanks, man!